# What cin.ignore() does exactly?

Tags: c++, cin

I've been told by my professor that every time I use `cin`, I should always follow it with `cin.ignore(100, '\n')`. But, I never understood why?

Here is an example:

```
const int MAX = 200;
char input[MAX];

cout << "Enter something: ";
    cin.get(input, MAX);
    cin.ignore(100, '\n'); //why necessary?!!
```

Comment: this is because the Enter key, that you pressed after typing in your something, counts as a character . If you don't read that key now then it will remain in the input buffer to be read by your next input operation, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @M.M what about the `100`?

Comment: @Obeguistake61 Take a look at [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: @Obeguistake61 It should be `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`

Comment: that is in the hope that you didn't type more than 100 characters of junk after MAX but before pressing Enter...  as noted by others it should be the maximum possible integer of the right type.

Comment: You should ask your professor what happens if there are more than 100 characters to be ignored. That's hardly good advice for robust code.

Comment: an alternative that doesn't require a size mention is `char ch; while (cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n');`

Comment: What does it do? It reads and discards from the input stream until it finds the end of line, `'\n'`, or has discarded 100 characters, whichever comes first. It's the whichever comes first part that everyone is warning you about. `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is the absolute maximum amount that can be in a stream, so it pretty much guarantees you'll find the end of line first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `ignore` *every* time, but it is good to use after formatted input, or in cases like yours where you only read a specified amount.

In your example, if I were to type in over 200 characters, any future input might be in for a rough surprise.

```
char input[200];
std::cin.get(input, 200);
```

After this executes, the first 200 characters were extracted, but anything after that is still left lying in the stream. It also leaves the newline (`'\n'`) character in it. Anytime you want to extract input after this, it'll read in the remaining characters from our previous input.

This happens with formatted input, too. Take this example:

```
int age;
std::string name;
std::cin >> age;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

What you want is to type in an age, like `32`, and a name, like "Bob". What happens is you input the age, and the program skips reading the name. When `std::cin` uses `>>` to read into variables, it leaves the `'\n'` character that was put into the stream by hitting enter. Then, `getline` reads in that newline character and stops, because it hit a newline and thinks it is done.

`ignore` solves this problem by discarding everything up to and including the next newline character, so that the extra input doesn't mess with future reads.

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

Answer (score 0):

> cin.ignore(100, '\n');

It ignores the first 100 characters, but if the function encounters '\n' before ignoring 100 characters, the function will stop discarding characters. So I assume that your professor wants you to ignore the rest of the data on the line unless it's longer than 100 characters.

Comment: Change the assumption to "Ignore the rest of the data on the line" and you are correct.

Comment: Thanks. Why did you answer the question in the comment section?

Comment: Change the assumption to "Ignore the rest of the data on the line unless it's longer than 100 characters"

Comment: @NeilKirk I never suggested that the assumption was correct, just what the instructor appears to have assumed. I'm going to take this as yet another lesson in why one should not use sarcasm on the Internet.

Comment: @acheigrec Some questions are well covered by the documentation and not really worth a formal answer. vsoftco beat me to the point on the documentation, and that left the important note other commentators brought up, but didn't exactly explain:: Why one should probably read more than 100 characters.